# Taxonomy term based content

Tags: taxonomy-terms

how do I get taxonomy based node content through custom query? I have taxonomy terms displayed using **drupal api function**. Now I need to fetch content based on terms id or name from **database**? Can any one please help me.Either using entity field query or SQL?

```
$tree=taxonomy_get_children(1);
 foreach ($tree as $term)
 {
 $item[] = $term->name;
 $child_term = taxonomy_get_children($term->tid);
 if (!empty($child_term))
 {
 <a href="?name=<?php print $term->tid; ?>">
 <?php
 print $term->name."<br>";
 ?>
 </a>
 foreach ($child_term as $child)
 {
 $item[] = $child->name;
 <a href="?tid=<?php print $child->tid; ?>" name="tid"> 
 <?php
 print $child->name."<br>";
 ?>
 </a>
 <?php
 $nodes = taxonomy_select_nodes($child->tid);
 $node = node_load_multiple($nodes);
 $nidd=(int)$node->nid;
 foreach($node as $node1):
 $tids = field_get_items('node', $node1, 'field_product_sub_cat');
 foreach ($tids as $tid){
 if($tid['tid'] == $child->tid){
 print $node1->title;
 print render(field_view_field('node', $node1, 'body')); 
 }
 }
 endforeach;
 else
 print $term->name."<br>";
```

[image: This is the snapshot of content type]

Answer (score 1):

You can get nodes as shown below:

```
$nodes = taxonomy_select_nodes($tid); // $tid is term id
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nodes);
```

Ref: `taxonomy_select_nodes` -> https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/7

**Update #1**

To get some fields out of $node object use following:

```
foreach($nodes as $node):
    $tids = field_get_items('node', $node, '<TERM_FIELD_NAME>');
    foreach ($tids as $tid){
        if($tid['tid'] == <SELECTED_TID>){
            print $node->title;
            print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'body')); 
            print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'tags')); 
        }
    }
endforeach;
```

To render complete node you can use `node_view` function. In order to render multiple nodes you can use `node_view_multiple` function as shown below:

```
$content = node_view_multiple($nodes, 'full');
print render($content);
```